# Controling the Wrap and Collapse in a Bootstrap Responsive Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about controlling the Bootstrap responsive layout of a nav strip.

I have a nav bar like so:

```
 [ button  1 ]          | Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 |       [ button  2 ]
```

The tabs are standard BS tabs and are grouped together in the center

How can I lay it out/code it so that when the screen size is reduced, it wraps like so:

```
[ button  1 ]           [ button  2 ]  
     | Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 |
```

insead of Button 2 going below the tabs (like normal HTML/CSS)?

Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible. You may have to do some unorthodox methods and it will probably take time but it's doable. My first suggestion would be to leave both the menu and submnu `display:inline`. Apply `position: absolute/relative` to the submenu and a decent margin. The re-structure accordingly according to the `@media`measurements.

Get as close as you can and come back with a code for us to debug. Right now, I don't think anyone will have this code already laid out for you.

Sounds interesting actually. I'll be interested

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. Wasn't really asking for someone to paste the code for it, but rather, I was hoping for something like "Oh, thats easy. Just add "dont-collapse" to the button classes" Whenever I get stumped, there's usually some simple code trick I didn't know about :)

Comment: It may be easier than you think. But you'll never know until you start

Comment: Technically, I started a long time ago....and only asked here after I ran out of ideas.